Attribute validation in graphql application
I'm using DataAnnotatedModelValidations package in my GraphQL application
Program.cs
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();


builder.Services
    .AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddDataAnnotationsValidator()
    .AddMutationType<Mutation>()
    .AddMutation<UserMutations>()
    .AddDefaultTransactionScopeHandler();
    
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapGraphQL("/");
app.Run();  

UserMutations.cs

[ExtendObjectType(typeof(Mutation))]
public class UserMutations
{
   [Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]
   public async  Task<User> CreateUserAsync(CreateUserInput input,
    [Service] UserService service
   ){
      await service.CreateUserAsync(input);
   
   }
}

CreateUserInput.cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class CreateUserInput{
    
    [MaxLength(8)]
    public string UserName{get;set;}
    
    [MaxLength(15)]
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    
    [MaxLength(15)]
    public string LastName{get;set;}
}

My problem is every time I am executing a mutation a validation process has priority over authorization. So if I am executing a mutation with invalid input and without required permission the expected behavior would be to get an unauthorized error but i get the list of validation errors. When I validate my input and run again than I got unauthorized error.
Is there a solution to make authorization process to have priority? Without required permission, the API must return "user is not authorized...", even if the input is full of error.
I added maxlength validator to input objecs.
I've added authorize attributes to my mutation endpoint.
I've executed a mutation without the required permission and with invalid data.
I got the validation failed error instead of not authorized exception.

This is a feature of how graphql works.
Your graphql schema describes what must be included in a request to your graphql endpoint. If the arguments supplied do not match the schema, then the request will be refused for being invalid.
You can read the docs here: https://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#sec-Required-Arguments

Does it mean that the request is executed even without authorization?

@EricMORAND The http request still makes it to the graphql endpoint, but the CreateUserAsync function is not called because the Authorize attribute checks whether the user is authenticated before the program calls it.

@EricMORAND The point is pretty much that the graphql schema describes what arguments you need to supply in order to call a query/mutation. If you don't provide those arguments then the query/mutation fails to comply with the schema, and the query/mutation is invalid before any of the code you've written is even run.

is the GraphQL server executing the validation even though the user is not authorized? If so, isn't it a concern: does it allow one to send an unauthorized request with a deliberately incorrect schema, just to trigger the validation?

I understood: that is how graphql works: so there is no way to add priority to the authorization? So my goal would be that, the request being resused for the user not having the required permission, and only if the user has the permission than refuse for not being valid. Is it possible the change the priority?

It's the wrong way of thinking about it. Imagine if you have a REST API which allows you to send a DELETE verb to yourapi.com/api/user/{userId}, and instead you send a DELETE verb to yourapi.com/api/user (with no userId). The REST API would return a 400 Bad Request because the request is bad regardless of whether you're authenticated.

For a real world example, If I send a drivers license application to the passport office, they'll reject it because the form I sent is wrong, regardless of whether or not I signed my name correctly.
